# How can I get a consistent return type from this function?

Tags: statistics, julia, regression, glm

Is there any way to get the function below to return a consistent type? I'm doing some work with [Julia GLM](https://github.com/JuliaStats/GLM.jl) (love it). I wrote a function that creates all of the possible regression combinations for a dataset. However, my current method of creating a [@formula](https://juliastats.org/StatsModels.jl/stable/formula/#Constructing-a-formula-programmatically-1) returns a different type for every different length of `rhs`.

```
using GLM

function compose(lhs::Symbol, rhs::AbstractVector{Symbol})
    ts = term.((1, rhs...))
    term(lhs) ~ sum(ts)
end
```

Using `@code_warntype` for a simple example returns the following

```
julia> @code_warntype compose(:y, [:x])
Variables
  #self#::Core.Compiler.Const(compose, false)
  lhs::Symbol
  rhs::Array{Symbol,1}
  ts::Any

Body::FormulaTerm{Term,_A} where _A
1 ─ %1 = Core.tuple(1)::Core.Compiler.Const((1,), false)
│   %2 = Core._apply(Core.tuple, %1, rhs)::Core.Compiler.PartialStruct(Tuple{Int64,Vararg{Symbol,N} where N}, Any[Core.Compiler.Const(1, false), Vararg{Symbol,N} where N])
│   %3 = Base.broadcasted(Main.term, %2)::Base.Broadcast.Broadcasted{Base.Broadcast.Style{Tuple},Nothing,typeof(term),_A} where _A<:Tuple
│        (ts = Base.materialize(%3))
│   %5 = Main.term(lhs)::Term
│   %6 = Main.sum(ts)::Any
│   %7 = (%5 ~ %6)::FormulaTerm{Term,_A} where _A
└──      return %7
```

And checking the return type of a few different inputs:

```
julia> compose(:y, [:x]) |> typeof
FormulaTerm{Term,Tuple{ConstantTerm{Int64},Term}}

julia> compose(:y, [:x1, :x2]) |> typeof
FormulaTerm{Term,Tuple{ConstantTerm{Int64},Term,Term}}
```

We see that as the length of `rhs` changes, the return type changes.

Can I change my `compose` function so that it always returns the same type? This isn't really a big issue. Compiling for each new number of regressors only takes ~70ms. This is really more of a "how can I improve my Julia skills?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think you can avoid type unstability here as `~` expects RHS to be a `Term` or a `Tuple` of `Term`s.

However, the most compilation cost you are paying is in `term.((1, rhs...))` as you invoke broadcasting which is expensive to compile. Here is how you can do it in a cheaper way:

```
function compose(lhs::Symbol, rhs::AbstractVector{Symbol})
    term(lhs) ~ ntuple(i -> i <= length(rhs) ? term(rhs[i]) : term(1) , length(rhs)+1)
end
```

or (this is a bit slower but more like your original code):

```
function compose(lhs::Symbol, rhs::AbstractVector{Symbol})
    term(lhs) ~ map(term, (1, rhs...))
end
```

Finally - if you are doing such computations maybe you can drop using the formula interface but feed to `lm` or `glm` directly matrices as RHS in which case it should be able to avoid extra compilation cost, e.g.:

```
julia> y = rand(10);

julia> x = rand(10, 2);

julia> @time lm(x,y);
  0.000048 seconds (18 allocations: 1.688 KiB)

julia> x = rand(10, 3);

julia> @time lm(x,y);
  0.000038 seconds (18 allocations: 2.016 KiB)

julia> y = rand(100);

julia> x = rand(100, 50);

julia> @time lm(x,y);
  0.000263 seconds (22 allocations: 121.172 KiB)
```